# Keep getting FATAL ECEPTION: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

Tags: java, android, xml

The application I was working on always gives me this error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.map.locationservice, PID: 12739 java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.

Below is my code and AndroidManifest.xml

```
package com.map.locationservice; 

import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

    double Latitude = 0;
    double Longitude = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(2 * 1000); // 2 second, in milliseconds

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Connect GoogleApiClient
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap google) {

        startLocationUpdates();

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            Latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            Longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int bundle) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}  




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.map.locationservice">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any idea why I keep get the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visit this tutorial and follow the steps carefully. It worked for me.
[Create Google Map Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92f4c2vHrPg)

before all that, have you created your project in google developers console and added your SHA1 key with your package and retrieved your API key..??

Comment: Yes I do have the API key, FATAL EXCEPTION happened after startLocationUpdates() is called

Comment: leave your current project, instead try creating a new project. If you are using android studio, then follow the video link I gave you, or else follow this tutorial which has complete explanations:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm. And if you are using eclipse, follow this tutorial: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/google-maps/android-google-maps-v2-tutorial/